A strengthening of the union-closed sets conjecture
[Originally posted at mathoverflow]
Let $\mathcal{F} = \{\{x_1, x_2\} : 1 \le x_1 \lt x_2 \le n \}$, $n \ge n_0$, and let $\mathcal{G} = \{G_1, \ldots, G_n\}$ be a partition of $\mathcal{F}$ in $n$ parts.
For any $G_i \in \mathcal{G}$ and $X = \{x_1, x_2\} \in \mathcal{F}$, let $g(i, X) = \min_{1 \le j \le 2}|\{ Y \in G_i : Y \cap X = \{x_j\} \}|$. Let $h(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n g(i,X)$.
Is it possible to prove or disprove that there exists $n_0$ such that for any $\mathcal{G}$ there always exists $Z \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $h(Z) \ge \Big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \Big\rfloor$?
Motivation related to the union-closed sets conjecture: suppose we have a union-closed family $\mathcal{H}$ with $n$ sets, and the intersection of any $\Big\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \Big\rfloor$ sets in $\mathcal{H}$ is empty, so that $\mathcal{H}$ is a counterexample to the union-closed sets conjecture. Extending the reasoning in the answers to this question it is not difficult to show that if we build $\mathcal{F}$ from $\mathcal{H}$, with a bijection between $(\{x_1, x_2\}, G_i)$ and $(\{H_1, H_2\}, H_i)$, $H_1, H_2, H_i \in \mathcal{H}$, $H_1 \cup H_2 = H_i$, then it must be $h(X) \lt \Big\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \Big\rfloor$ for any $X = \{x_1, x_2\} \in \mathcal{F}$, otherwise we would have some $ p \not= q$ such that $H_p = H_q$. In other words, proving the statement in the question would imply the union-closed sets conjecture. But the converse is not true, therefore we have a strengthening of the conjecture. But the problem in this question "seems" somewhat easier than the union-closed sets conjecture.
$n_0 \ge 8$ because I found counterexamples for $n = 5$ and $n = 7$. However, from $8$ above, by taking $30000$ random partitions for each value of $n$, it seems that the statement in the question holds, with a margin increasing with $n$. Clearly, random samples do not prove anything. Here is $\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor$ (first line) compared with the minimum of the maximum value of $h(X)$ (second line) for $n \ge 3$ and $30000$ tests:
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8, 8, 9, 9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15
0,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,10,11,12,12,13,13,14,15,15,15,17,17,18,18

I have tried to solve an Integer Linear Program for the problem, with the following minimums for $3 \le n \le 7$: $0,1,1,1,1$. Unfortunately, while the solver takes a few seconds for $n = 7$, it gets out of memory after about $5$ hours for $n = 8$.
The question can be formulated in terms of graph edge labeling of a complete graph $K_n$ with up to $n$ labels.
Any hint?

Let $n = q^2+q+1$ and consider a projective plane of order $q$. It has $n$ points and $n$ lines such that every line contains $q+1$ points and every point lies on $q+1$ lines. Through every two points, there is a unique line, and every two lines intersect at a unique point.
If $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n$ are the lines, let $G_i$ to be the set of all pairs of points on $\ell_i$, for $i=1, \dots, n$.
Now consider a pair $X = \{x_1, x_2\}$. There is a unique line $\ell_i$ containing $x_1, x_2$, and $q-1$ other points. For that line, we will have $g(i,X) = q-1$: there are $q-1$ pairs $\{x_1, x\} \in G_i$ and $q-1$ pairs $\{x_2, x\} \in G_i$, where $x \ne x_1, x_2$.
Every other line $\ell_j$ contains at most one of $x_1$ or $x_2$. If $\ell_j$ does not contain $x_1$, then there are $0$ pairs of the form $\{x_1, x\}$ in $G_j$, and so $g(j,X) = 0$; similarly if $\ell_j$ does not contain $x_2$. Therefore $g(j,X) = 0$ for all $j \ne i$.
Therefore $h(X) = q-1$, and this is true for any $X$. As a result, the highest possible value of $h$ for this partition is far from $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$: it is closer to $\sqrt n$.

Since we want the colors $G_1, \dots, G_n$ to be very unevenly distributed here, a construction like this is reasonable to consider, but actually - and this is surprising - I'm pretty sure that the random partition also does better than $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$, though by less of a margin.
Specifically, let's look at $g(i,X)$ for an arbitrary pair $X = \{x_1, x_2\}$ in a random partition. The number of pairs in $G_i$ that meet $x_1$ is asymptotically $\text{Poisson}(\lambda = 1)$, and the number of pairs in $G_i$ that meet $x_2$ is asymptotically and independently $\text{Poisson}(\lambda = 1)$. The expectation of the min of two Poissons is annoying to compute as a sum, but Mathematica tells me that numerically it is about $0.476$. So $\mathbb E[g(i,X)] \approx 0.476$ and therefore $\mathbb E[h(X)] \approx 0.476 n$ for a fixed $X$.
I will leave the rest as a heuristic argument because I don't want to delve into the guts of the calculation. But the terms in $g(1,X) + \dots + g(n,X)$ should be nearly independent, so in a central-limit-like way, $h(X)$ should be typically $\mathbb E[h(X)] \pm C \sqrt n$, and it should be less than $0.477 n + C \sqrt{n \log n}$ except with probability $1 - \frac1{n^3}$. I think a good strategy to take to prove this, were one so inclined, would be Azuma's inequality with an edge exposure martingale, a la Chapter 7 of Alon and Spencer's Probabilistic Method.
Anyway, at that point, there is only a $\frac1{n^3}$ probability that $h(X) > 0.477n + C \sqrt{n \log n}$, for some not-too-large $C$ we could work out if we wanted. By the union bound, there is only a $\frac1n$ probability that this holds for any $X$. Therefore, for large $n$, we will almost always get a partition where all $h(X)$ are below $\frac12n$ by a tiny but significant multiple of $n$.
